# Scheduled Emails

Tags: javascript, php

Im trying to setup scheduled emails to send to my customers with reports and balance of sales during one day. So at the end of the day the customer would automatically receive an email with all the reports. Does anyone have any good suggestions?

Comment: `if($time == something) { mail() }`

Comment: I use cron jobs to do that.

Comment: ^ Yeah, *that's the ticket.*

Comment: so i should call my php script via cronjob schedule function? what would be the best way since php is server side and js is client side?

Comment: @Granit What does JS have to do with this? Cron is server-side, so's PHP. JS has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

If this app has a server of its own, I will go with cron jobs. Scheduling and firing up events at a certain time is best done by cron.

If you're on Linux, 
 you can `issue > crontab -e`

this will open the cronjob editor, in there you want to make sure 
 there is no extra space and the lines are exact and script are called from 
 its full path.

```
 * * * * * /path/to/email-customers.php
```

lets say you want to check every half hour if reporting requests were sent to customers every half hour, you'd have something like

```
 */30 * * * * /path/to/email-customers.php
```

In your case, if you just run it once a day

To run once, lets say daily at 10 pm you should do something like this -

```
0 22 * * * /path/to/email-customers.php
```

after you're done, issue > crontab -l

this will list your cronjobs to make sure it ran. you can also output the results of the cronjob to a file by doing `> email_customers_cron_result.txt` at the end of your cronjob line or you can easily check/tailf the cron log to see what happened or how it went.

```
0 22 * * * /path/to/email-customers.php /path/to/email_customers_cron_result.txt
```

Comment: will just `/path/to/email-customers.php` work or do you have to put `php /path/to/email-customers.php`

Comment: you need to put php, it won't know what else to use.